# Is it possible to push DNS search suffices from DNS server to client?

Tags: domain-name-system, intranet, android, ipad

Our (active directory, windows-server-based) intranet used to be called "intranet", and DNS worked fine for windows machines and iPads/Android devices.

We have changed it to be "apps.intranet", and it still works for windows machines, but no longer for iPads/Android devices.

I think this is because out windows clients are configured to append .company.com when searching DNS, to make it a fully qualified lookup (this search suffix list is pushed to the PCs via AD group policies).

I must admit, though, I don't know why it worked with just "intranet"!

Does anyone know if it's possible to get DNS to "tell" the iPads/Android devices to append .company.com ... or how we can make it work some other way (but still using the multi-label, non-qualified DNS names) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at your DHCP server, are you supplying the option for a search suffix to your scopes?

Comment: This is correct. You can't do this from your DNS servers, you have to add "search domains" or "suffixes" to the clients, which can be done via DHCP.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Well, yes I think this is working ok. Our wireless router has the "domain" entered, and when I connect a windows laptop, and do ipconfig /all, I can see the DNS search suffix list is "company.com"... so, I don't know why the iPad/Android are having a problem - is it something to do with the "spec"? Could it be that by introducing the "." the iPad thinks it should now be fully qualified?

Comment: why not just start referencing everything by FQDN?